# What is the sefardic custom concerning wearing tallis katan?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, shacharis-morning-prayer, provenance, tallit-katan

I have heard that sefardim wear a tallis katan only for shacharis and then take it off.  Is that so?  If so, when did this custom arise and why?

Comment: Likely, there isn't one Sefardic custom. Sefardim, not unlike Ashkenazim, come in many different varieties.

Comment: you mean for shabbat or every days?

Comment: Not likely. A tallit katan is meant to be worn with one's clothing throughout the day. There are some sephardim who keep the tzitzit tucked in though

Comment: i'm not aware of this idea of only wearing tallith qatan for only shacharith. It's been my experience that most Sephardic shuls have people who wear their tallith qatan with the sithsith tucked in. Which means that in general you don't know who is wearing one and who isn't. Also, many sephardim don't make a b'rakha over a tallit qatan, because they don't feel it matches the blessing of "lihitateif" (being wrapped in) sithsith.

Comment: @Aaron The word is [ציצת](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0415.htm#38).